# Повторение пройденного пути

Tags: искусственный-интеллект, алгоритм, c++

Я тут пишу игру и мне нужно как-то сделать повторение пройденного пути игрока. Когда умирает игрок, то появляется его мертвая копия (как бы тень) и идет по тому же пути, который был раньше, а второй экземпляр  создается заново и управляется игроком. Я не могу придумать, как это сделать, посидел минут 15, поразмыслил, думал запоминать координаты, записывать в буфер, потом читать и прикинул, что это сильно сложно, замусорю буфер и все зависнет. Есть какие нибудь идеи?

Пример игры "супер мясной парень (super meat boy)": в конце каждого уровня показывается все его смерти и как он прошел таки этот уровень.

Comment: Ну да, нужно запоминать координаты (можно даже не все, а только т.н. контрольные точки - точки, в которых игрок меняет направление движения). Только про буфер не понятно - необязательно же хранить весь путь в ОЗУ, можно периодически его дампить в файл временный, а по смерти игрока считывать оттуда координаты и удалять файл.

Comment: На такой вопрос вы вряд ли получите удовлетворительный ответ. Это то же самое, что спросить: "Хочу сделать свой интернет, но не знаю как, может взломать тот, что есть?"

Comment: @Asen, нормальный вопрос, не понимаю о чем вы. Автор уже сам все придумал, только в деталях реализации, видимо, сомневается.

Comment: Super Meat Boy The Best!

Comment: @VioLet, спасибо, вроде бы ясно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Представьте себе игру, аналогичную `Super Meat Boy` и тот факт, что вы хотели бы сделать **систему реплеев** для нее.

То есть, скажем, реализовать команду *"показать, как игрок проходил уровень в последний раз".*

> - Допустим, что внутриигровые события у вас отрисовываются на `60fps`. Тогда
>   вам необходимо взять какой-либо второй
>   таймер, например, со скоростью
>   обновления в `20fps` и на каждый фрейм
>   записывать текущее *абсолютное*
>   местоположение персонажа относительно
>   начала уровня.
> - Дальше, естественно, необходимо научиться *"проигрывать"* такой буфер.
> - Научились делать один реплей - теперь записывайте в память последние
>   `N` реплеев и объединяйте их при
>   воспроизведении.
> - Ваше замечание про *"замусорю буфер и все зависнет"* - это смешно :)

Comment: 1) Допустим сделал
2) Каким образом можно проигрывать буфер?
3) Разберемся
4) Так посмеемся же (:

В общем спасибо! Понятно объяснил по такому алгоритму и буду действовать.

Answer (score 0):

Второй вариант lock-step симуляция (обрабатывать все действия игрока с заданной дискретностью, например, 60 слотов в секунду).

Записывать все действия игрока, чтобы потом их в точности воспроизвести.

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть игровые *события* - нажатие клавиши или кнопки мыши для перемещения(Смотря как это у вас реализовано).

К примеру персонаж перемещается на клавиши(Direction): <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> <kbd>←</kbd> <kbd>→</kbd>

В игре есть объект для записи каждого *события* - `EventInfo`.
Поля объекта `EventInfo`:

- `EventPoint`: Координаты персонажа когда была нажата клавиша;
- `Direction`: Направление;
- `Speed`: Скорость.

Есть список событий `EventsList`. Список создается каждый раз когда создается персонаж(в конструкторе).
По событиям нажатия клавиш, создаем объект `EventInfo` и заносим в список.

Когда персонаж умирает, создается его копия и ей передается сформированный список. Копия начинает по очереди считывать события и двигаться:

1. Считывается событие;
2. Начинается движение в указанном направлении(`Direction`) и с заданной скоростью(`Speed`);
3. Дошел до точки следующего события, повторяем все с пункта 1.

По усмотрению создаете новые события, например:

- Смерть персонажа.
- Столкновение(Персонаж останавливается).

Список можете сохранять в файл, и реализовать - просмотр повторов.